# Prove the inequality of $u$ and $v$

Tags: inequality

> If $u \geq v \geq 1$ then prove that, $$9u^3+4v^2+2\leq 6u^2+9uv^2$$

I can't progress at all regarding this inequality. Any idea will be helpful. Is there any non-calculus solution of the inequality?

Comment: There seems to be something wrong I believe. Note that for $u = v$ your inequality simplifies to $u^2 \leq 1$ which does not hold for all $u \geq 1$.

Comment: @MatthiasKlupsch: Yes you are right. Edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** $u = 1+a+b$, $v = 1+b$, $a, b \geq 0$, and simplify the inequality.

Note: Please check the sign to make sure your problem is correctly stated.